# Calculated members: SSAS

Tags: ssas, olap, cubes

In the "Calculations" tab of an SSAS cube project, does "Measures" dimension represent all measures within the measure groups as well?

For instance:
Patron Revenue has measures actual win, cash in, cash out....
Patron Redemption has measures operator pay, redeeming dollars, redeeming comp...

In calculation tab, 
[Actual Gross Profit] is calculated as 
[Measures].[Actual Win]-[Measures].[Operator Pay]-[Measures].[Redeeming Comp]-[Measures].[Redeeming Dollars]

So, in this case, does the [Measures] dimension represent the measures such as actual win, operator pay, redeeming comp and redeeming dollars etc located in different measure groups?

Help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Just as [Measures] is treated as a dimension, each measure group/measure is treated like a dimension hierarchy/member, so that you can slice and dice in MDX across any "dimension"; this means you can do things like have a query sliced on two dimensions and a measure; with one dimension on rows, then either the measures on columns (with the dimension implicit in the values) or a dimension on the columns, with the measure implicit.

Comment: thanx jeremy...well I am not using MDX. WHat I am doing is, I am writing a TSQL query to verify the calculated measure works correctly. But, when I browse the cube and drag one of them down, the value it shows does not match with that of TSQL query.

Comment: How do I trace back the actual columns used/joined to get the result using TSQL as given by  [Measures].[Actual Win]-[Measures].[Operator Pay]-[Measures].[Redeeming Comp]-[Measures].[Redeeming Dollars] in MDX?

SO far, my approach has been a look up into the measure properties and find the table/view and the column name used. 
The joining column has been a difficult part, because the DSV looks very messy and is hard to follow the lines. 

Any suggestions appreciated